# Airpods connect but no music

Tags: ios, bluetooth, airpods

I have an issue...My AirPods don’t have any connection Issue when Bluetooth is turned on. But when Bluetooth is turnt off...my iPhone has more difficulty in recognizing the AirPods when I open the case and it seems to sync but actually it doesn’t since Bluetooth is still turnt off,thus the music still plays from the iPhone’s speakers.

However when I reset the AirPods...during the « first » connection my iPhone recognizes the AirPods and they connect automatically ( with Bluetooth turnt off) and the music plays from the AirPods with no problem.

Can Anyone help me please ??

Comment: Are you sure Bluetooth is off? The gray icon in control center doesn’t mean it’s off, it’ll have a slash through it if it was and it can only be turned off in settings.

Comment: Ah...i didn’t know about that...but still why does it connect with the grey icon during the first connection and does not do the same for further connections until I turn the Bluetooth icon to « Blue » mannually

Comment: That’s expected behavior. What do you mean by “reset AirPods”? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208086

Comment: I mean long pressing the button at the back of the case while the airpods are connected...it’s like the phone forgets about the airpods and the connection animation  is the Same as the first time I connected the AirPods.

Comment: From what you are saying AIrPods do not connect unless I turn the Bluetooth icon in the control centre ON manually ?

Comment: That’s right, other than the exceptions listed on the article. See answer for my assessment of the situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Disconnect from Bluetooth accessories](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208086) (Apple):

> Open Control Center and tap [the Bluetooth icon]￼. The icon dims and your device disconnects from any accessory it's connected to, except for Apple Watch, Instant Hotspot, Apple Pencil, and Continuity features, like Handoff. If Bluetooth is turned off, you won’t be able to connect your iOS device to your Bluetooth accessories until:
>
> - You turn on Bluetooth in Control Center.
> - You connect to a Bluetooth accessory in Settings > Bluetooth.
> - It's 5 AM local time.
> - You restart your device.

It’s expected behavior that Bluetooth devices won’t connect (when Bluetooth is dimmed in control center) without one of the above exceptions.

It seems like resetting AirPods is a special case that mimics connecting to a Bluetooth accessory directly in settings, and is therefore an exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot !...I was actually scared that my AirPods could be fake. Reassured now.

Comment: Glad it was helpful! Would appreciate an upvote and marking my answer as accepted. Cheers

Comment: I have less than 15 followers...so my upvote isn’t publicly displayed